# Shell script to load the SqlServer table data into csv File

Tags: sql, sql-server, bash, shell, unix

Need a Unix shell script to load the sqlServer table data into csv File.

Could some one please share the sample shell script.

Comment: @Moushmi come on, give a little respect for this place and show what's you already done for your case and where you exactly stuck ? i'm pretty sure that everyone here including me want to help you just give us a chance :))

Comment: I used command : sqlcmd -S ServerName -U UserName -P Password -d DatabaseName -Q "select * from TableName;"  -o "outputFileName.csv " -W -s","     but I am not getting proper output data.  I am getting data as with Hypension after header column name as ---------------------------,

Comment: Import the csv throught the "import data wizard" (right click on th catalog). save the SSIS package. You can reuse it.

Comment: sqlcmd -S $SQLHOSTNAME -U $SQLUSERNAME -P $SQLPASSWORD -d $SQLDATABASE -s"      " -W -w 3000 -Q "SET NOCOUNT ON; $query;" | sed 2d >$csv_filename

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below Working:-->

sqlcmd -S $SQLHOSTNAME -U $SQLUSERNAME -P $SQLPASSWORD -d $SQLDATABASE -s"      " -W -w 3000 -Q "SET NOCOUNT ON; $query;" | sed 2d >$csv_filename

Comment: Can any way to compress the output file?